# How to convert sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix" into regular matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix with dimension of 65100*65100 which is a sparse matrix of class "dsCMatrix" in R. How could I get rid of this sparse matrix because I have a difficulty to save this matrix as "write" function in R. Is there anyway to save the whole sparse matrix as a regular matrix?

Regards

Saj

Comment: Possibly should be migrated to CV. May find [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/dimensionality-reduction-svd-or-pca-on-a-large-sparse-matrix) helpful.

Comment: @ WhiteViking: after I used as.matrix(),I got this error message: Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

Comment: As usual @RichardScriven is right :-) Can you add a reproducible example that results in the `problem too large` error? For example using random data.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `as.matrix()` on the `dsCMatrix`. Here's an example:

```
library(Matrix)
m <- Matrix(toeplitz(c(10, 0, 1, 0, 3)), sparse = TRUE)
m

# 5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#                
# [1,] 10  .  1  .  3
# [2,]  . 10  .  1  .
# [3,]  1  . 10  .  1
# [4,]  .  1  . 10  .
# [5,]  3  .  1  . 10

as.matrix(m)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   10    0    1    0    3
# [2,]    0   10    0    1    0
# [3,]    1    0   10    0    1
# [4,]    0    1    0   10    0
# [5,]    3    0    1    0   10
```

Comment: this suggestion works for small matrix dimension but not for my case. Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105